# How to join very large csv file with another one?

Tags: csv, join, large-files

I would like to join two CSV files based on one field. One of these files has ~1TB (250 mln records, 2080 columns). The other one is smaller, has a few columns and 20 mln records. I was trying to us python's dask package for this specific task but can not handle joining phase which is really consuming. Unfortunately, I have to do this using Windows machine with 120 GB of memory so Hadoop is not an option here. I have Python, R and SQL Server.

Thanks in advance for help as I got stuck!

Comment: Well I would tell you to load the small one in memory than read the big on one line at a time, join with the information in memory and write in a new file the result. You will only have one line + the small file in memory. If this is not that small, then ordering both field previously should allow to only read one line per file (if the condition to join is simple). Please give us more detail about the problem you have.

Comment: Thank you @AxelH for a hint. This approach is a good idea but really time consuming. Loading only one line, then joining this line with all records in another file and save it to external file is taking some time. Have to do this 250 mln times so a lot of I/O operations. When I am thinking about this and trying to find some good approach, in my mind is something like: maybe there is some language/tool which is best for such a task like perl or even bash? What do you think? Maybe using Python/R and loading files into memory is not a good solution.